# Need to pick a Project Portfolio tool to manage dependencies BETWEEN projects

Tags: data-visualization, project-management

I need some advice on Portfolio Management Software for our team. We are currently using Asana to manage individual projects, but we presently don’t have a way to manage dependencies/conflicts between projects.

I’ve been doing research for the past few days now, and while there are a LOT of good software options, and I just don’t have the time or the patience to review them all. It seems the main competitors are JIRA, Asana, Monday.com and ProductBoard.

**Requirements**

- Easy to use tool with low learning curve
- Feature rich out of the box
- Trouble Ticket tool integration
- Project graphing tool (GANTT like)
- Able to track projects as a whole and be able to drill-down into a projects sub-tasks
- Able to assign and track resources between projects
- Ability to assign ***times and dependencies*** at a project and a
  resource level (which resources are spread across multiple projects,
  etc.)
- Plan on a page (Single pane of glass)
- Align to Big Rock Goals as top line business drivers
- Screen mockup idea (below)

[image: Ideal Project Portfolio Feature to show dependencies]

**Questions**

- Should key project stakeholders be emailed when their project component (task, resource, etc.) has a conflict/pending deadline?

**Risks**

- Price (how much would it cost to adopt new tool)
- Time to integrate
- Resources available
- Adoption (ramp up time / learning curve time)

I would prefer JIRA but it seems it is geared more towards individual projects. Is Asana the best tool then at the portfolio level?

I welcome any advice on how to pick the best PPM tool.